# What countries do for people from China, over stay their visa because can't return because corona virus?

Tags: visas, health, overstaying

Many country and airline cancel airplane travel from/to China because corona virus. This force many people from China over stay their visa. Will countries extend their visa?

Comment: This will, most likely be considered a case of **force majeure**, just as it is in China for foreigners. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152687/95267

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question, this is asking the inverse. However, I still think the question is too vague and should ask about a specific country.

Comment: This will vary by country. In some countries, visas are only for entry, so one cannot overstay a visa; rather, one can overstay one's status, and it is possible to apply for extension of status, depending on the country and exact status the person has.